# Stange Message on "sudo" commands, after upgrading WSL From 16 to 18 about "getrlimit"

Tags: sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting a strange message whenever I run `sudo`, ever since upgrading my MS Windows 10 WSL Ubuntu 16 --> Ubuntu 18.
The message is

> sudo: setrlimit: Function not implemented

The upgrade seemed to go very well, with the only hickup coming at the very end, when it complained that the ssh configuration files had been modified.  After some strangeness with trying to compare configuration files, I finally just told it to overwrite the old files, and things seemed to finish smoothly.

Comment: What is the WSL build version? it looks like support for `setrlimit` was added in [Build 16257](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-16257)

Comment: In the MS store, it tells me that my MS Windows 10 version is 15053.1659, and there is an update button. But, trying to use the button takes me to a broken URL. 

Attempting to update from the Start button, by doing a search and selecting Windows Update tells me that I am fully up to date, but notes that I haven't updated since August). Yes, this is a company locked down PC, so I am not sure how much of the MS Windows update configuration I can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that steeldriver had the right of it.  The issue was caused by my out-of-date version of MS Windows 10.  Removing and re-installing WSL didn't do any good.

However, once I was finally able to find a path that would upgrade the version of MS Windows, then it was trivial to install WSL, followed by doing a "Get" from the MS App Store to install the latest Ubuntu.

After the typical initialization, getting my version of Ubuntu *fully* current was just a matter of typing `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y`.

Answer (score 0):

**Though not a direct answer to your problem**, I recommend you reinstall, which will give you a clean cosmic distro - it's in store working out of the box. If you broke sudo package or dependencies and maybe broke even worse stuff during dist-upgrade, you're better off reinstalling. You can access WSL files you need to backup directly from the host if you have issues backing up from inside WSL.

WSL is a subsystem and not core Linux and dist-upgrading may not always work out of the box. I personally had issuses with some packages going from Bionic to Cosmic.

Comment: I went back and completely removed WSL (down to turning off the Windows feature, rebooting, turning it back on, rebooting etc), then tried to install it from the MS Store.  No joy.  Trying to install via "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature-Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" (as recommended by the MS Store), also fails cuz MS Windows can't find its own command. <sigh>